# How to capture duplicate rules in flows?

Tags: duplicate-management, visual-flows

one of the steps of my flow is to create a contact. The users enter in the interface all the details and click next, my flow then tries to save the contact; however, if salesforce detects a duplicate user via the [duplicate rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_create.htm&type=5), then it only throws an error message. Is there any way to detect the duplicate error and also capture the duplicate matches(records)? I would like to display all the duplicate matches and provide a nicer error message to the end-user.

I know that in apex is possible to detect the [duplicate errors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm) and also capture the duplicate matches. So I think I could create an [Apex Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm) and detect the duplicate error and return the duplicate matches, but I am looking for an out-of-box solution for flows or an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does your duplicate rule block the creation of the contact or just warn? If it is blocking then you should be able to catch the fault/error then go to another screen to show similar contacts after getting them first. To show multiple fields in a tabular format, I would recommend that you use the the unofficial SF Datatable component.
https://unofficialsf.com/datatable-lightning-web-component-for-flow-screens-2/